# long long in C++

Tags: c++, types

I'm creating a game engine and It's going to have support for Microsoft Windows X86 and X64 editions. When I'm creating the custom typedefs, do I have to specify "typedef unsigned long long" if the version is X86 and "typedef unsigned long" when the version is X64?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The long long type is 64 bits on all compilers that support it. (The C/C++ standards say it has to be at least 64 bits; I don't think there are any systems yet that support larger types.) If you just want a 64 bit integer typedef, you can use long long without any worries.

The C99 and C++11 standards provide a new header, <stdint.h> or <cstdint>, that already has a set of fixed size typedefs, so you can just use uint64_t. Visual Studio 2010 supports this but I don't think VS2008 does.

The C and C++ standards only specify minimum sizes for the standard integer types:

- char is specified as at least 8 bits
- short is specified as at least 16 bits
- int is specified as at least 16 bits
- long is specified as at least 32 bits
- long long is specified as at least 64 bits

Comment: To clarify, sadly VS2008 does not have <cstdint> or <stdint.h>. Also, I thought that GCC liked to make `int` 64-bits on 64-bit compilers?

Comment: i've never seen a 64bit `int` ever. Basically the only thing that changes size in x64 is the pointer size.

Comment: I'm sorry, where in the standard does it mention that long long has to be at least 64 bits? I can't find it even in the `7.1.5.2 Simple type specifiers` table. (That is, in the 2003 C++ standard)

Comment: It's not in the 2003 C++ standard. It's in the 1999 C standard and the 2011 C++ standard.

Comment: What do you mean by "in practice"? On modern DSP's `char` is often 32-bits. On 16-bit processors `int` is 16-bits. Your answer is heavily desktop biased.

Comment: @Brian: to be fair so is the question heavily Windows biassed, but since `long` in the Win64 ABI is 32 bits, I suppose the "in practice" was trying to generalize beyond that, so "always" was wrong.

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <cstdint>
```

and use `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`, etc.

Comment: I already know about that, but I want to define my own without worrying about external references.

Comment: Note that this requires C++0x support. Boost provides a similar header.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Really, really, really... use <cstdint>. If you define your own types, you drive anyone else reading your code nuts, and you run in trouble once you decide to port to a different platform.

Comment: @jsvcycling: It's not an external reference; it's the _standard_ library. It's like saying "std::vector" or "size_t" is an "external reference."

Comment: I'm sorry but why would you NOT use this header? The work is done for you.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I'm using an in-house compiler. It uses the C++ syntax, but not the standard library (we wrote our own customized version).

Comment: @Nicol - didn't you already say that's not quite true? C++0x isn't the dominant C++ standard. C++11 is imminent if not already here, but it won't be the effective standard for a little while yet - that depends more on compiler writers than on documents. In the meantime, C++0x support is limited, inconsistent between compilers, and presumably only works at all if you specify certain options.

Comment: @jsvcycling: When this is the case, that should be the *first* piece of information you mention. Around here, we tend toward recommending the use of the standard library *unless given reason not to.*

Comment: Never mind this question anymore, just talked to the guy who wrote our "standard library". He said he'll implement everything from <cstdint> and will have it done by tomorrow. Thanks everyone for you answers and comments.

Comment: @jsvcycling: here's a public domain version of `stdint.h` that originated with the MinGW project and has worked for me in VC6 and later. http://snipplr.com/view/18199/stdinth/  I make no promises other than that, but it might give your guy a bit of a head start.

Comment: @Michael Burr, cool, I'll pass it on to the guy who is developing our "standard library"!

Answer (score 1):

Since 64-bit Windows uses the LLP64 data model and the Visual C++ compiler too, of course, you should be safe using `typedef unsigned long long` for both versions, since in LLP64 `long` remains 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

`long long` has been working for decades in most C++ compilers (due to the C heritage), althoug it wasn't part of the standard.

There is one little snag: If you compile C++ code with `long long` with GNU C++ at the `-pedantic` warning level, it will complain that `long long` is not standard C++. This is True. Actually it is also true that `long long` works. On GNU C++. And every other compiler. This does not have to be a problem except you sometimes run into people that force you to blindly enable all compiler warning options, and fix all the trouble that surfaces.

Funny thing is that at the same time GNU C++ will let you use `uint64_t` without complaining. This is also C, not C++, except that it is less portable because compiler vendors are slow to implement C99.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippet from the Qt source code:

```
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN) && !defined(Q_CC_GNU) && !defined(Q_CC_MWERKS)
#  define Q_INT64_C(c) c ## i64    /* signed 64 bit constant */
#  define Q_UINT64_C(c) c ## ui64   /* unsigned 64 bit constant */
typedef __int64 qint64;            /* 64 bit signed */
typedef unsigned __int64 quint64;  /* 64 bit unsigned */
#else
#  define Q_INT64_C(c) static_cast<long long>(c ## LL)     /* signed 64 bit constant */
#  define Q_UINT64_C(c) static_cast<unsigned long long>(c ## ULL) /* unsigned 64 bit constant */
typedef long long qint64;           /* 64 bit signed */
typedef unsigned long long quint64; /* 64 bit unsigned */
#endif

typedef qint64 qlonglong;
typedef quint64 qulonglong;
```

We can see that unsigned __int64 and __int64 are used on windows.

Comment: This is old stuff. `long long` and `unsigned long long` has worked as well for several releases of the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Try [boost integer.hpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/integer/doc/html/index.html). It has uint64_t with is guranteed to be unsigned 64 bits on all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning Visual Studio (different versions), [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) is helpful

I never knew long was only 32 bit on 64bit Windows... until I ran into weird problems with msSinceEpoch.